# How do I get better performance with Watch Dogs in Windows 10, compared to Windows 7?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-7, windows-10, hardware, watch-dogs

I am attempting to play Watch Dogs on Windows 10. The game ran fine at low settings on a Windows 7 PC (at least 30-35 fps) but Windows 10 does not give me even 20 fps.

I have dual booted Windows 7 and Windows 10 for comparisons. The specs are as follows:

- **CPU:** Intel I3 5005u @ 2GHZ
- **RAM:** 4 GB DDR3 ram 1600mhz
- **GPU:** Intel HD 5500 Graphics
- **OS**:

  - Windows 7 (latest updates installed), vs
  - Windows 10 1909

I have all the latest drivers for both OSs.

One other thing I noticed is that after exiting the game in Windows 10, CPU usage was always around 30-50%, RAM usage was around 3.1 GB of 3.9 GB and in Windows 7 CPU usage was not going above 20% and even ram usage was only 1.5 GB - 2GB.

I even edited the xml file to put graphics setting at lowest in Windows 10 but no good happened.

How can I increase the performance so that the game runs well on Windows 10?

Comment: Might be a driver issue. Are you using the same driver version in both Windows 7 and 10?

Comment: @galcticninja Yes both the OS have same graphics driver which was last updated in Feb 2020.

Comment: I think this might be a Windows 10 issue. It seems that Windows 10 uses more system resources, especially RAM, compared to Windows 7. I've noticed the same in my other 4 GB RAM PCs. They don't fare too well with gaming in Windows 10, even though they did just fine in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

### Try disabling Windows 10's Game Mode

Despite Microsoft's claims to the contrary, it seems that [some people](https://www.techradar.com/au/news/windows-10-users-should-turn-this-feature-off-now-for-better-gaming-performance) have been getting [poorer gaming results](https://www.pcgamer.com/au/try-turning-off-windows-10s-game-mode-if-your-games-are-stuttering-or-freezing/) with 'Game Mode' enabled. What's more, it's enabled by default - so if you've done a fresh install of Windows 10, it's probably still turned on. To disable it:

- Click Start -> 'Settings' Cog
- Click 'Gaming'
- Along the left-hand menu, find 'Game Mode'
- Click the toggle to turn it off.

Comment: Hi @Robotnik! Thanks for reply. I tried playing Watch Dogs with Game mode off and noticed a minor **positive** result. However this still didn't make the game as smooth as in Windows 7. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: @CrispyCon - Without knowing specifics of your PC (including stuff installed on it) I can only guess from here - but generally I would say that Windows 10 tries to do a lot in the background, and so do a lot of third party applications - try disabling/removing background processes, stuff from startup etc.

Comment: I have already disabled all startup apps except audio driver app and Windows Defender. Even my Windows update is disabled. I think I'll need to close some background processes every time I am about to start the game or install unofficial Windows Lite xD. Anyways thanks for assistance.

Comment: @CrispyCon no problem, glad to help even if it's just a little bit :). Best of luck with your search! Let us know if you find the culprit :)